# One point compactification of $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: general-topology

> What will be one point compactification of $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$?

It looks like it will be union of two circles touching at a point. But do I write a Mathematical proof to justify my claim?

Comment: kabhi algebra bhi pucha kar. Hume bhi mauka de

Answer (score 5):

- The space you suggested is compact.
- If you remove the touching point you obtain a space homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: What is the homeomorphism?

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal : Perhaps my answers comes closer to saying what the homeomorphism is, although it's still not explicit.  But if there is a general statement that two spaces must be homeomorphic if their one-point compactifications are homeomorphic, one could then ask how to construct a homeomorphism that proves that.  Maybe that's worth another stackexchange question.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal This is a characterisation of the one-point compactification (which is known to be essentially unique). If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and we have a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ and a point $p \in Y$ such that $Y \setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $X$.

Answer (score 4):

What is an open neighborhood of the one additional point in the one-point compactification?  It contains the one additional point and the complement of a closed subset of the space that you're compactifying.

What is an open neighborhood of the union of two circles glued together at one point?  The same thing.